# How to add shadow 'wings' to a centered content div

Tags: html, css

I've got a [stylized page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G2jTL.png) that I've been using to practice JavaScript in but recently I found out that some of my CSS was blocking my document listener from hearing mouse clicks targeted at embedded elements beyond the target of the culprit CSS.

Culprit CSS

```css
.backDrop {

  background-color: #FFF;
  height: 100vh; width: 720px;
  margin: auto;
  /*box-shadow: creates ill-desired corners;*/
}
.backDrop:before {

  box-shadow: 0 0 20px -20px black;/* shrinks and blurs for a soft shadow*/
  content:'';
  height: 200vh;
  position: absolute; /* <-- THIS  [but there's no shadow without it]*/
  width: 720px;
}
```

---

So to circumvent this problem I implemented a parent `div` classed `wrapper` and embedded `backDrop` along with two sister `div`s classed `backDrop_leftShadow` and `backDrop_rightShadow` to each side of it. Then I created two alternatively oriented background images of a horizontal gradient that fades from black to transparent, and assigned them to the CSS for my 'wing' `div`s.

Each `div` follows a normal indentation scheme, but I've had to separate them from each other with `<!--comment-->`s to prevent white space from mucking up the rendered layout. From there I moved the `viewWidth` and `margin` CSS from `backDrop` to `wrapper` and replaced the `viewWidth` units in `backDrop` with percentage and pixel units. The gradients I made are 7 pixels wide, so I made `wrapper` 14 pixels wider than `backDrop` and each wing `div` 7 pixels wide. Then I tried every combination of `display: inline-block, inline, block;` I could think of in the CSS for each sister `div` inside `wrapper` --but nothing seems to work.

```js
var element = document.getElementById("addItem");
element.addEventListener('click', promptFunction);

function promptFunction() {
  element.innerHTML = square(window.prompt('inputvar'));
}

function square(x) {
  return x * x;
}
```

```css
body {

 background-color: #3A3C3D;   /*alt color #CCA #3A3C3D*/
 margin: 0;
 overflow: hidden;     /*top stop the extended shadow element height from causing the page to scroll*/
}



.backDrop {

 background-color: #FFF;    /*alt colors #ACA null #CCA*/
 display: inline-block;
 height: 100%; width: 720px;
}
.backDrop_leftShadow {

 background-image: url("http://s14.postimg.org/7p3o980el/left_shadow.png");
 background-repeat: repeat-y;
 display: inline-block;
 height: 100%;
 width: 7px;
}
.backDrop_rightShadow {

 background-image: url("http://s14.postimg.org/cc9qaznrh/right_shadow.png");
 background-repeat: repeat-y;
 display: inline-block;
 height: 100%;
 width: 7px;
}



.wrapper {

 background-color: red;
 width: 734px;
 margin: auto;
}



.interface {

 background-color: rgba(255, 0 , 0, 0);
 background-image: url("../code/assets/experimenting pot/img/isometric platforms.png");
 border-left: 2px solid red;
 border-radius: 5px;
 box-shadow: 0 0 5px -2px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
 margin: auto;
 height: 270px; width: 480px;
}



.lineBreak {

 height: 16px;
}
```

```html
<body><!--All the comments you'll see below are meant to null white space between layout elements--><!--
 --><div class="wrapper"><!--
     --><div class="backDrop_leftShadow"></div><!--
     --><div class="backDrop" id="backDrop"><!--
         --><div class="lineBreak" id="addItem">click here to square</div><!--
         --><div class="lineBreak"></div><!--
         --><div class="interface">yo</div>
        </div><!--
     --><div class="backDrop_rightShadow"></div></div>

 <!--<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="../javascript/viewportControl.js"></script>-->

 </body>
```

Note: I attempted to upload my gradients to an image hosting site so they could be loaded from here, but I can't seem to get that to work right either. I'll be happy to fix that problem if someone knows how. --But more interestingly, the exact code is producing two different renders depending on nothing more than whether it's being rendered [locally](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hHzIS.png) or through [stackoverflow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GeyGp.png). When [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uRzoR.png) is what I'm going for. Or more accurately, and as I've already said, [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G2jTL.png). --the 'STACKOVERFLOW' and 'LOCAL' text was edited in with an image editor.

Comment: I am finding a really tough time understanding what you are aiming for (there's too much noise in the question). Are you trying to add a background? Are you trying to add an event listener to the bigger box?

Comment: Question: part one
I want my page to look like this http://i.imgur.com/LzcysUs.png and still allow event listeners to hear mouse clicks targeted at elements embedded x levels deep, which is why I can't rely on pseudo elements to create my box shadow because apparently... and absurdly... they... block JavaScript. I know, it blows my mind too. So it seems to keep the functionality of my page, I must sacrifice, or compromise, the aesthetic. One compromise would be to  apply a box shadow to the actual element instead of using a pseudo element, but that method creates rounds shadow corners.

Comment: Question: part two
The rest describes what I've tried to do to achieve that aesthetic without using CSS. IE; I created two dedicated divs for my shadow images which sit on either side of `backDrop`, and encased all three of them in a `wrapper` `div` styled to hold the embedded three tightly against each other (requiring me to clutter my html with comment tags) and centered in context of the page. I've included pictures showing how close I am to achieving this. The last four links in the post should help clear up any remaining confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with the first solution that you tried was related to the positioning of the pseudo-element. As it had `position:absolute` it went on top of the other elements and that caused the issue.

You could easily solve that by also using `z-index`: if you set the value of `z-index` to -1, that element will go to the bottom of the stack and won't affect with the event listeners.

Here is a demo of that using your code:

```js
var element = document.getElementById("addItem");
element.addEventListener('click', promptFunction);

function promptFunction() {
  element.innerHTML = square(window.prompt('inputvar'));
}

function square(x) {
  return x * x;
}
```

```css
body {

 background-color: #3A3C3D;   /*alt color #CCA #3A3C3D*/
 margin: 0;
 overflow: hidden;     /*top stop the extended shadow element height from causing the page to scroll*/
}


.backDrop {

  background-color: #FFF;
  height: 100vh; width: 720px;
  margin: auto;
  /*box-shadow: creates ill-desired corners;*/
}
.backDrop:before {

  box-shadow: 0 0 20px black;/* shrinks and blurs for a soft shadow*/
  content:'';
  height: 200vh;
  position: absolute; /* <-- THIS  [but there's no shadow without it]*/
  width: 720px;
  z-index:-1;
  margin-top:-20px; /* to avoid the issue with the borders that you commented */
}

.wrapper {

 width: 734px;
 margin: auto;
}



.interface {

 background-color: rgba(255, 0 , 0, 0);
 background-image: url("../code/assets/experimenting pot/img/isometric platforms.png");
 border-left: 2px solid red;
 border-radius: 5px;
 box-shadow: 0 0 5px -2px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
 margin: auto;
 height: 270px; width: 480px;
}



.lineBreak {

 height: 16px;
}
```

```html
<body><!--All the comments you'll see below are meant to null white space between layout elements--><!--
 --><div class="wrapper"><!--
     --><div class="backDrop" id="backDrop"><!--
         --><div class="lineBreak" id="addItem">click here to square</div><!--
         --><div class="lineBreak"></div><!--
         --><div class="interface">yo</div>
        </div></div>

 <!--<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="../javascript/viewportControl.js"></script>-->

 </body>
```

---

The second part is related to using percentages as values for heights. The heights of the parents need to be set or otherwise the percentage will fail (because 100% of 0 is 0).

Comment: I've read about z-index before, but I find it difficult to comprehend the abstraction  in context of divs and html. Is there a tool out there that can analyze and report the complete z index in an html document with multiple elements so I can get a feel for where everything is and how it gets there?